# Connect three servers in lan over internet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

We have three Windows Server 2008 R2 servers in different physical locations.
We would like to connect them over the internet as if they were in LAN.
My guess is to use VPN, but is there another option?

Would it be possible that if one server is rebooted for updates or power failure it connects back in LAN automatically after booting (without administrator logging in)?

Comment: When you say "you want them as if they were in a LAN" do you mean you want them to be layer 2 adjacent?

Comment: @jliendo please forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm not sure what do you mean. What I mean by like in lan is to be able to use local ip address between them (like 192.168.x.x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to set up some sort of VPN, or routing tunnel between your three different sites. This is probably best done on the routers themselves rather than between the servers. Depending on your hardware, there's a probably a bunch of different options and topologies for you to choose from.

A simple option would be to have simple point-to-point tunnels between each location. You would need three in total and the technology used for these tunnels would be determined by whether you need features like encryption.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you, please, recommend me what to use if we want to use encryption? Thanks.

Comment: You'll get encryption by using something like a VPN tunnel, as opposed to a simple GRE tunnel. Again, depending on your routing equipment, setting up a site-to-site VPN tunnel (or 3, in your case) should be a fairly simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Hamachi is what you want, a pier-to-pier mesh VPN

https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/hamachi2/

Comment: Peer to peer in fact. I don't want to go near the fisheries (or the boatshed) again. ;)